# Salesforce IDE starting error

Tags: jvm, salesforce

I have installed the standalone IDE for salesforce force.com platform. On trying to start the ide i am getting "JVM terminated. Exit Code=-1" error. Any idea what this error code means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common loading error for force.com IDE.

There are different solutions. Try anyone of these:

A) Change the workspace location.

OR

B) (i). Install Eclipse 3.6 for Java Developers (Helios) from the link http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2
Click your operating system from the window on your right.

(ii). Using the below link, follow the instructions to install Force.com IDE plugin for Eclipse 3.6 http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.6

OR

C) In the default Force.com IDE install directory:

```
  C:\Program Files\salesforce.com\Force.com IDE
```

Locate the config file:

```
  forceide
```

And comment out the following at the end of the file (note the leading #):

```
#-vmargs
#-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#-Xms256m
#-Xmx1024m
#-XX:PermSize=128M
#-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

I hope it works now.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I tried all three options, restarted my machine. But i continue to get the same problem. What else could be possibly wrong?

Comment: Sorry all, i got this working now. Strangely there were 2 ini files in my machine and i had changed in the wrong one. I changed the other & its working fine. Thanks all.

Comment: The site for loading the Force.com plugin is apparently dead.

No repository found at http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/latest.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of various reasons. Say, if you do not have enough memory (RAM) as specified in config file(forceide.ini). As said in this link [Force.com IDE – JVM terminated](http://www.alokagrawal.com/blog/archives/70) , probably reduce `MaxPermSize` in config file to say 256M and check.

Answer (score 1):

This exact thing happened to me a few days ago.
My setup is:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- jre7 64 bit
- Force.com IDE 64 bit

When I ran the java auto update to update my jre it installed the 32 bit version (a whole other gripe). So I manually downloaded the 64 bit version of the jre installed it over the top of the 32 bit version and the IDE started working again.